# How do I refresh the DOM of a jquery mobile page when I dynamically add radio buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-mobile

I'm adding buttons to a radio field dynamically, the function that adds the elements looks like this

```
 function updateNetworks(data){

            $.each(data.networks, function(key, network) {

                var radioItem = '<input type="radio" name="radio_network" id="radio_network_'+network.id+'" value="'+network.id+'"  /><label for="radio_network_'+network.id+'">'+network.name+'</label>';

                $('#radio').append(radioItem);
            });

            $('input:[name=radio_network]:radio').checkboxradio("refresh")
        }
```

The HTML dom element

```
   <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="radio">

            <legend>Choose a network:</legend>

        </fieldset>
```

The function is updating the dom fine but none of the jquery mobile styles are being applied to the buttons, is there some way to refresh the added radio buttons?

**working code

```
 function updateNetworks(data){

            $.each(data.networks, function(key, network) {

                var radioItem = '<input type="radio" name="radio_network" id="radio_network_'+network.id+'" value="'+network.id+'"  /><label for="radio_network_'+network.id+'">'+network.name+'</label>';

                $('#radio').append(radioItem).trigger('create');
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `.trigger('create');` should do the trick. [More info on jQuery mobile dom manipulation here.](http://jquerymobiledictionary.pl/faq.html)